# Quiero poner un slider de texto y un botón al centro de este video pero no se crear el overlay, me ayudan?

Tags: html5

```html
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="http://216.119.68.130/projects/synetb/video/synet.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aquí puedes llevar un curso completo de full desarrollo web http://www.freecodecamp.com :)

Answer (score 1):

Esto es lo que buscas?

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.embed-responsive {
 position: relative;
}

.boton {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%%;
 display: flex;
 z-index: 1000;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.click {
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: black;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 text-decoration: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px;
 display: block;
 margin: 20% auto;
}

.click:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 transition: .2s;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="http://216.119.68.130/projects/synetb/video/synet.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="boton">
      <a class="click" href="#">Click</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que pides que el vídeo quede de fondo y delante de él aparezca algo de texto y un botón, como suelen verse últimamente las webs. Bueno, supongo que hay varias formas de hacerlo, yo hice algo parecido para una web jugando con *display: table* y el *display:cell* junto con ir insertando el contenido en diferentes contenedores.

El siguiente código te ocupará el ancho y alto de tu pantalla, si no es lo que deseas, puedes utilizar las medidas que tu quieras.

```css
.embed-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

.embed-responsive-item {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

source {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

section {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: table;
   top: 0;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: rgba(42, 40, 43, 0.7);
}

section div.vcenter {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: none;
}

.inner {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 170%;
    line-height: 1.6;
    padding: 10px;
}

.content {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="http://216.119.68.130/projects/synetb/video/synet.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<section>
  <div class="vcenter">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="content">
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <button type="submit">Botón</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```